# SpringBoot OAuth2 authentication

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am trying an OAuth2 authentication in SpringBoot App using GitHub authentication. When trying to access the secured endpoint /securedHello,  I am not getting the GitHub Login option and it is getting redirected to /login. Please find the code details below. Requesting help.

**pom**

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.16</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <java.version>17</java.version>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

** Config **

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChainOAuth2(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/orders/v1/hello").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository(){
        return new ClientRegistrationRepository() {
            @Override
            public ClientRegistration findByRegistrationId(String registrationId) {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

** Controller **

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/orders/v1")
public class OAuth2Controller {

    // http://localhost:8080/orders/v1/hello
    @GetMapping(value = "/hello", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getHello() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello World");
    }

    //Secured
    // http://localhost:8080/orders/v1/securedHello
    @GetMapping(value = "/securedHello", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> securedHello() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello World... Secured");
    }

}
```

**properties**

```
spring.security.oath2.client.registration.github.client-id=<<client_id>>
spring.security.oath2.client.registration.github.client-secret=<<client_secret>>
```

** Web UI **

[image]